# How to convert Date Time string to "Date Month"[5 December] format in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I have date time object with value like "5/12/2014 3:14:55 PM", but i want to show this to page as "5 December", So how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Read [**this**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from MSDN for all custom date and time format specifiers.